# Where did the term "broadcasting" come from?

Tags: numpy, octave

I'm trying to find the origin of the term, and whether there's an alternative names for it. All the usages I can find on the web point back to numpy manual. Any idea if it's been used before?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about etymology.

Comment: Matlab refers to a certain kind of broadcasting as "singleton expansion"; see `bsxfun`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It originally derived from [Yorick](https://software.llnl.gov/yorick-doc/), an older array-focused programming language that many of the original NumPy (née Numeric) designers were familiar with.

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/matrix-sig/1995-November/000143.html

https://software.llnl.gov/yorick-doc/manual/yorick_50.html#Broadcasting

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/broadcasting-in-numpy-58856f926d73
and checked https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yorick_(programming_language) it seems that at the time 95-96 multiple libraries implemented some form of broadcasting.

It makes me wonder where broadcasting originated from.

Answer (score 1):

According to [online Etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=broadcast):

> 1767, adjective, in reference to the spreading of seed, from broad
>   (adj.) + past participle of cast (v.). Figurative use is recorded from
>   1785. Modern media use began with radio (1922, adjective and noun). As a verb, recorded from 1813 in an agricultural sense, 1829 in a
>   figurative sense, 1921 in reference to radio.

Sometime later, definitions like [this](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enwiki/1278404) came about:

> In telecommunication and information theory, broadcasting refers to a
>   method of transferring a message to all recipients simultaneously.

The definition, [for Numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), builds on the above:

> The term broadcasting describes how numpy treats arrays with different
>   shapes during arithmetic operations. Subject to certain constraints,
>   the smaller array is “broadcast” across the larger array so that they
>   have compatible shapes.